# gitea by docker on Windows

Tags: windows, docker, gitea

Hello，I use docker to install on windows,but I can not clone code by git,however,I can use a browser to access websites on windows and I can clone code In the container，please help,what do I need to do

I disable firewall, no.

Comment: Please take a few minutes to complete the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how this site works before you begin posting. I'd suggest you pay special attention to [ask]. Learning how the site works and what our expectations are will greatly improve your experiences here going forward.